# How flow control occurs between ADSL modem and DSLAM?

Tags: networking, ethernet, adsl, adsl-router

When Adsl modem gets the ethernet packets, it forwards them to DSLAM at Central Office by phone lines,as i know ethernet protocol uses pause frames for control flow so what kind of protocol is there between the ADSL modem and DSLAM? What happens if DSLAM is not available to process data,is there a control mechanism?

Comment: Consumer grade ADSL uses [Asynchronous Transfer Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_Transfer_Mode). ATM approximately maps to the three lowest layers of the ISO-OSI reference model: network layer, data link layer, and physical layer

Comment: [ATM Congestion Control](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cis788-95/ftp/atm_cong/)

Comment: The DSLAM only cares about ADSL frames, the next layer is ATM which operates back to the RAS where the network becomes TCP/IP once more. ATM switches/multiplexers will be configures by the ISP and some VC/VPs may get priority over others (voice is high priority, then business then residential for example).

Comment: I'm not sure that i've understood, so is there a protocol  or not? If DSLAM onyl cares about ADSL frames, what happens if DSLAM can't forward frames, does it just drop frames?